# Minimum amount of rectangles to create a 2-dimensional matrix

Tags: algorithms, optimization, arrays, matrices, lower-bounds

From [this codegolf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154193/matrices-generated-using-rectangles).

Consider an $r$ by $c$ matrix of nonnegative integers, called $M$. You also have a zero matrix of the same dimensions, called $N$. A "move" consists of replacing a rectangle of numbers within $N$ with any positive nonzero integer.

Valid "moves":

```
2 moves:
0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0  =>  1 1 1 1
0 2 0 0      0 2 0 0
0 2 0 0      0 2 0 0

2 2 0 0
2 2 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Invalid moves:

```
0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0

2nd move invalid:
2 2 2 0      2 2 2 0
2 2 2 0  =>  2 0 2 0
2 2 2 0      2 2 2 0
```

A few examples of valid $M$ matrices:

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 7 0 5

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0

0
```

The question is, how do you find the minimum amount of moves required to recreate $M$ out of $N$?

Comment: Try [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Comment: @D.W. I'll take a look.